# I want to read call logs in the android

Tags: android, phone-call, calllog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I retrieve recently used contacts in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674156/how-can-i-retrieve-recently-used-contacts-in-android)

I want to read recently used contacts.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**1. Create observer:**

```
class CustomContentObserver extends ContentObserver {

        public CustomContentObserver(Handler handler) {
            super(handler);

        }

        @Override public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() { 
            return false; 
        }

        public void logCallLog() {
            long dialed;
            String columns[]=new String[] {
                    CallLog.Calls._ID, 
                    CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, 
                    CallLog.Calls.DATE, 
                    CallLog.Calls.DURATION, 
                    CallLog.Calls.TYPE};
            Cursor c;
            c = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls"),
                    columns, null, null, "Calls._ID DESC"); //last record first
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                dialed=c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE));                 
                Log.i("CallLog","type: " + c.getString(4) + "Call to number: "+number+", registered at: "+new Date(dialed).toString());
            }
        }

        public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
            super.onChange(selfChange);
            Log.d("PhoneService", "StringsContentObserver.onChange( " + selfChange + ")");
            logCallLog();
        }

}
```

**2. Register observer:**

```
 Uri mediaUri = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI;
        Log.d("PhoneService", "The Encoded path of the media Uri is "
                + mediaUri.getEncodedPath());
        CustomContentObserver custObser = new CustomContentObserver(handler);
        imageContentRsr.registerContentObserver(mediaUri, false, custObser);
```

**EDIT:**
As of Jellybean (4.1), you now need the permission:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
```

For this to work and not throw a Permission Denial exception

Comment: what type of object is imagecontentRsr?

Comment: try getContentResolver()

Comment: thanks I've tried with getContentResolver() and works, but outside  ContentObserver class. under this class it says that getContentReseolver is undefined.

Comment: What is `imageContentRsr' and where to register the Observer? I am trying in Activity.. Please suggest